# Await doesn't work with BeginInvoke?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, c#-5.0

I was experimenting with the new C# await feature. I made a custom awaiter implementation as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            T1();
            Console.WriteLine("After t1");
        }

        private static async void T1()
        {
            CustomAwaitable a = new Sleeper().Sleep();
            object r = await a;
            Console.WriteLine("sleeper awakes " + r);
        }
    }

    internal class CustomAwaitable
    {
        private readonly Sleeper m_sleeper;

        public CustomAwaitable(Sleeper s)
        {
            m_sleeper = s;
        }

        public MyAwaiter GetAwaiter()
        {
            return new MyAwaiter(m_sleeper);
        }
    }

    internal class Sleeper
    {
        public ManualResetEvent Handle = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public bool Awake { get; set; }

        public int Result
        {
            get { return Environment.TickCount; }
        }

        public CustomAwaitable Sleep()
        {
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                Awake = true;
                Handle.Set();
            }).Start();
            Console.WriteLine("begin sleeping " + Result);
            return new CustomAwaitable(this);
        }
    }

    internal class MyAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
    {
        private readonly Sleeper m_sleeper;

        public MyAwaiter(Sleeper sleeper)
        {
            m_sleeper = sleeper;
        }

        public bool IsCompleted
        {
            get { return m_sleeper.Awake; }
        }

        public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
        {
            // This works!!
            //new Thread(() => 
            //{
            //  m_sleeper.Handle.WaitOne();
            //  continuation();
            //}).Start();

            // This doesn't work!!
            Action k = () =>
            {
                m_sleeper.Handle.WaitOne();
                continuation();
            };

            k.BeginInvoke(null, null);
        }

        public object GetResult()
        {
            return m_sleeper.Result;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that, in the OnCompleted method, when I schedule the continuation code execution using BeginInvoke, the GetResult method is never called. But when I create a thread manually to do the same thing, everything works as expected. I know that BeginInvoke uses the thread pool internally, which should work the same way as the thread approach (I know that there is a thread count limit with thread pool, but it is negligible in this case as I am not running anything else).

What are your ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Should the `public CustomAwaitable Sleep()` return a Task?

Comment: I don't think so. As long as the class has a GetAwaiter() that returns a valid Awaiter, await should work.

Comment: Pause the debugger. Where do all the threads stand?

Comment: It works just fine for me. Are you sure that you're just not returning from `Main` too quickly?

Comment: @bigfoot, as Stephen points out, your `Main` apparently exits before `T1` is completed. Simply make `T1` return a `Task` rather than `void` and do blocking wait on it in `Main`: `T1().Wait();`. In general, avoid `async void` methods, they're only good for fire-and-forget event handlers.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys! I found out why. Thread pool threads are in background mode, and are terminated when the main thread returns. So the continuation code doesn't have the chance to run in this case. The thread created manually is a foreground thread and will survive and run its code after the main thread exits.